# Let P(2c-1, c+2) be a variable point

Tags: solution-verification, intuition

Let $P(2c-1, c+2)$ be a variable point. $PM$ and $PN$ are perpendiculars from $P$ on two fixed lines which meet at $O$, the origin; $MQ$, $NQ$ are drawn parallel to the fixed straight lines to meet at $Q$. Prove that the locus of $Q$ is a straight line.

If $M $ and $ N $ are foot of perpendiculars to the two lines and $MQ$ and $NQ$ are parallel to the given lines doesn't that make $ Q = O $(origin). If I am wrong can somebody explain the question to me.

Comment: Hi, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Comment: Your expression for $P$ is not very understandable, do you mean $P(2c,c+2)$?

Comment: I edited it sorry for before

Comment: This question was a silly misunderstanding . The one MQ and NQ lines are supposed to be parallel to the given lines which contains N and M respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ is moving along a straight line.  If the two straight lines on which we project $P$ are $n_1^T r = 0$ and $n_2^T r = 0$ where $r = [x, y]^T $ , and $n_1, n_2$ are unit normals to the lines, then

$M = A_1 P$

$N = A_2 P$, where

$A_1 = (I - n_1 n_1^T)$,

$A_2 = (I - n_2 n_2^T) $

Point $Q = OM + ON = (A_1 + A_2) P $

Since $P$ moves on a straight line, i.e. $P = P_0 + t d $ then

$Q = (A_1 + A_2) ( P_0 + t d_1 ) = (A_1 + A_2) P_0 + t (A_1 + A_2) d $

which the equation of another line.  Hence, the locus of point $Q$ is a straight line.

Comment: I don't quite understand the notations and what they represent is their another simpler solution

Comment: Let line 1 is $\vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{r}=0$ and line 2 is $\vec{n_2}\cdot\vec{r}=0$, where $\vec{n_1}$ and $\vec{n_2}$ are unit normals. Then $\vec{MP}=(\vec{OP}\cdot \vec{n_1})\vec{n_1}$, $\vec{OM}=\vec{OP}-\vec{MP}=\vec{OP}-(\vec{OP}\cdot \vec{n_1})\vec{n_1}$, $\vec{ON}=\vec{OP}-(\vec{OP}\cdot \vec{n_2})\vec{n_2}$, $\vec{OQ}=\vec{OM}+\vec{ON}=2\vec{OP}-(\vec{OP}\cdot \vec{n_1})\vec{n_1}-(\vec{OP}\cdot \vec{n_2})\vec{n_2}=f(\vec{OP})$. $f(\vec{OP})$ is additive function of $\vec{OP}$, then if $\vec{OP}=\vec{a}+\vec{b}t$, then $\vec{OQ}=f(\vec{a})+f(\vec{b})t$ which describes straight line.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a simpler solution.